# Rechargable Batteries for Radio mics

Tags: rechargable, radio, microphone

Hi,

I am interested in finding out peoples experiences with using rechargeable batteries in radio mics. In the past, I have always used fresh Duracell's with back-up's simply because I didn't want to find myself without full power. Now, with all these new rechargeables on the market, has anyone any experience with them in the case of radio's and what sort of life do they have on a day to day set. We have Sennheiser ew100 G3 and the sk 100 G3 series.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a bunch. But recently I bought the Sanyo Eneloop, and they are very cheap and great! They last me a whole day on my G3s without any worries. I combine this with a Sony CycleEnergy, which takes 15 min to charge them up. With these high speed chargers you get the same amount of time out of your batteries, but the difference is that the life of them is shorter. So after a year or two you'll probably need to throw them away. Not a big deal when paying $12.95 for a pack of 4 Eneloops.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I work as a sound engineer at a large theatre in Chicago, and NiMh is the way to go.  Most of the brand names will work alright (energizer, duracell, rayovac), but what will serve you better is a higher mAH rating on the battery.  We use 'Tenergy' brand with nice charger bays that 'refresh' the battery as well as recharge it (also indicate charge level).  We've had great success going this way.

Answer (score 1):

NiMh batteries will last the whole day or even more.

Answer (score 1):

I second the Eneloop AA's. They're new technology - Low self discharge, which is perfect for wireless. For my Micron wireless i use 9v iPower 520 mAH batteries though. They last good 6-7 hours too.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using nickel-zinc batteries in my Sennheiser EW100 G4.

- NiZn has a nominal voltage of 1.6 V, which makes them usable in devices for which the 1.2V of NiMH is too low.
- I use Ansmann batteries, their AA batteries have a capacity of 2500 mWh (1560 mAh).
- I tested a new set in a handheld mic, this provided power for something like 8 hours.
- I use a set for 2 church services (~2 h each) before recharging.
- with one use per week (two hours), the batteries last several years before their capacity drops below 50%.

NiZn has two drawbacks:

1. The discharge curve is uninformative. They stay at 1.6 V until they're almost empty, and then the voltage falls off a cliff and the mic shuts down without warning. The battery indicator on the mic is useless (it's based on voltage).
2. Running these batteries empty damages them. I've had several sets that were used until empty, and now cannot be charged any more. So I set up a conservative charging scheme where we recharge after two services so the battery should never get below 50% charge.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's all about Powerex AA's with Maha chargers and iPower 9-volts with their own brand of charger, based on advice I've gotten online from production soundies. Duracell Alkalines for backups. All AA's are stored in [these](http://countycomm.com/CBH.htm), with specific orientations up or down to show that they're expended or fully charged. Oof, those Duracell rechargeables are junk and have given me nothing but trouble.

Comment: @NoiseJockey - Any reason you use iPower 9V over the PowerEx 9V?  I know the PowerEx are cheaper, but is there a performance problem?

Comment: @VCProd, I just went right to the iPower 9V's because of their reputation amongst production mixers and boom ops. I've not tried the PowerEx 9V's!